# Проксировать и кешировать статику

Tags: изображения, nginx, веб-сервер, кэширование

Есть некий удаленный сервис, по функционалу похож на каталог товаров. У него есть АПИ благодаря которому мы можем выводить этот список товаров на нашем проекте. Но вот незадача, удаленный ресурс частенько падает.

Кешировать данные товаров через АПИ мы научились, и по факту, на нашем проекте работаем с кешированными данными. Но вся беда в картинках каждого товара. Как только падает удаленный сервис, у нас пропадают картинки товаров, что очень сильно сказывается на юзабилити проекта, и вообще выглядит убого.

Для понимания объемов. Товаров в каталоге около 10000. Картинок у каждого в среднем 20. Плюс 3 размера каждой картинки, итого около 600 000 различных изображений. Это около 80ГБ данных. Список товаров динамичен, т.е. товары могут добавляться, могут удаляться. Но URL каждой картинки уникален, т.е. ситуации что по такому то URL картинка вдруг изменилась, быть не может.

Есть идея - сделать php скрипт проксирующий картинки с сервиса, попутно складывая их к нам на сервер, и дальше отдавая их nginx-ом напрямую. В принципе это реализуемо. Но честно сказать, мне бы очень хотелось исключить php и вообще какую бы то ни было динамику в этом месте.

Чисто теоретически возможно ли средствами nginx сделать что то подобное? Или Varnish? Какой из них мне подойдет больше?

Идея у меня в общих чертах следующая - для статики прописать в качестве бекэнда удаленный сервис, и время кеша поставить допустим месяц. Возможно ли это? Но тут встает проблема, если упадет сервис, возможно ли заставить nginx продолжать отдавать устаревший кеш?

Или все же выбросить дурные мысли из головы, и сделать, как я говорил, скрипт. Опять же встает вопрос, как удалять устаревшие картинки. Т.е. в идеале бы удалять картинки из нашего хранилища, к которым не обращались допустим месяц.

В общем подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону мне копать.

Comment: PHP вам может понадобиться только 1 раз на 1 картинку, при первом обращении к ней, чтобы стянуть рисунок с чужого сервера к себе в хранилище.

Comment: @Visman немного поправлю, 3 раза на каждую картинку (3 размера каждой картинки). Но сути это в общем то не меняет.
Суть в том что тут меня смущает то что мне кажется при использовании php это будет ощутимо дольше чем если бы мы проксировали например nginx-ом. Так например открыть один товар - это нужно подгрузить 60 файлов с удаленного сервера. PHP в этом плане не очень быстрый же...

Comment: Посмотрите в гугль по этому https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 запросу. Возможно nginx справится с этим делом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В целом проблему решил так. NGINX слушает два порта 80 и 8085, общая схема:
[image: Взаимодействие между инстансами NGINX]
<sub>(источник: [intsystem.org](https://intsystem.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Untitled2.png))</sub>

Конфиг основного инстанса:

```
server {
    #...
    error_page 403 404 405 415 500 502 503 504 /nophoto/nophoto.jpg;

    location ~* .*(?<extension>jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ {
        error_page 403 404 405 415 500 502 503 504 /nophoto/nophoto.$extension;
        access_log off;

        limit_except GET {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* ^/images/item\d?/.+$ {
            expires max;

            try_files "/imdata${uri}" @proxy_local;
        }
    }

    location @proxy_local {
        proxy_temp_path /var/www/cust_images/data/temp;

        proxy_store    "${root_path}/imdata${uri}";
        proxy_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;

        proxy_intercept_errors on;

        proxy_method            GET;
        proxy_pass_request_body        off;
        proxy_pass_request_headers    off;

        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8085;
    }
    #...
}
```

Конфиг внутреннего инстанса

```
proxy_cache_path
    /var/www/cust_images/data/cache
    levels=1:2
    keys_zone=remoteimages:10m
    inactive=60m
    max_size=1G;

server {
    #...
    image_filter_jpeg_quality     80;
    image_filter_buffer           10M;
    image_filter_interlace        on;

    location ~* ^(?<request_1>/images/item\d?/\d+/\d+/)(?<request_size>small|medium|large|full)(?<request_2>\_\d+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))$ {
        proxy_temp_path               /var/www/cust_images/data/temp;

        proxy_cache                   remoteimages;
        proxy_cache_key               $proxy_host$uri;

        proxy_cache_min_uses          1;
        proxy_cache_lock              on;

        proxy_cache_valid             any                                 1m;
        proxy_cache_valid             400 404 408 415 500 502 503 504     1h;

        proxy_cache_use_stale         error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

        proxy_connect_timeout         5s;
        proxy_read_timeout            5s;
        proxy_send_timeout            5s;

        proxy_method                  GET;
        proxy_pass_request_body       off;
        proxy_pass_request_headers    off;

        set $width  "-";
        set $height "-";

        location ~* .+/full\_\d+\.[a-z]+$ {
            proxy_pass "http://images.service.com${request_1}large${request_2}";

            set $width  "-";
            set $height "-";
        }

        location ~* .+/large\_\d+\.[a-z]+$ {
            if (-f "${root_path}/imdata${request_1}full${request_2}") {
                return 481;
            }

            proxy_pass "http://images.service.com${request_1}large${request_2}";

            set $width  625;
            set $height "-";
        }

        location ~* .+/medium\_\d+\.[a-z]+$ {
            if (-f "${root_path}/imdata${request_1}full${request_2}") {
                return 482;
            }

            if (-f "${root_path}/imdata${request_1}large${request_2}") {
                return 482;
            }

            proxy_pass "http://images.service.com${request_1}medium${request_2}";

            set $width  380;
            set $height "-";
        }

        location ~* .+/small\_\d+\.[a-z]+$ {
            if (-f "${root_path}/imdata${request_1}full${request_2}") {
                return 483;
            }

            if (-f "${root_path}/imdata${request_1}large${request_2}") {
                return 483;
            }

            if (-f "${root_path}/imdata${request_1}medium${request_2}") {
                return 483;
            }

            proxy_pass "http://images.service.com${request_1}small${request_2}";

            set $width  "-";
            set $height 100;
        }

        image_filter resize $width $height;
    }

    error_page 481 =200 @local_large;
    error_page 482 =200 @local_medium;
    error_page 483 =200 @local_small;

    location @local_large {
        try_files "/imdata${request_1}full${request_2}" =404;

        image_filter resize 625 -;
    }

    location @local_medium {
        try_files "/imdata${request_1}large${request_2}" "/imdata${request_1}full${request_2}" =404;

        image_filter resize 380 -;
    }

    location @local_small {
        try_files "/imdata${request_1}medium${request_2}" "/imdata${request_1}large${request_2}" "/imdata${request_1}full${request_2}" =404;

        image_filter resize - 100;
    }
}
```

В итоге проксируемые картинки сохраняются на сервере. При этом если уже есть картинка бОльшего размера, то берется она и обращения к удаленному сервису нет, что дает огромный плюс в плане скорости и надежности.

В целом подробнее см. тут:
https://intsystem.org/server/proxy-resize-cache-images-with-nginx/

Comment: Старайтесь, пж-та, писать более развёрнутые ответы и не ограничиваться одной ссылкой, коя может стать однажды "битой". К тому же, правилами сообщества определяется, что ответ-ссылка допустим лишь в очень малом кол-ве случаев, в коим данный ответ не может быть отнесён.

Comment: Ответ из одной лишь ссылки, добавьте контент.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо за подсказку. Написал развернутый ответ.

Comment: Плюс за схему )

Comment: @NickVolynkin рад, что вам понравилось)

Answer (score 3):

До появления кеширования в nginx был ещё один способ сохранять данные получаемые с другого сервера - [proxy_store](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_store). Он подходит вам лучше всего. А удалять можно find-ом по времени создания.

Comment: Хм. Довольно удобно получается. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Постарайтесь убедить владельца удаленного сервиса улучшить его работу. Это самый оптимальный путь.

Comment: Боюсь убедить не получится, мы пытались, тут поможет только грубая физическая сила... но они находятся слишком далеко... Поэтому, пока только кеширование.